# Pass model to controller function in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Where did I go wrong in my code? When you click on the button the first number and second input number have to show.

```js
app.controller('AddSum', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.sum = 0;
    $scope.add = function (fnumber, snumber) {
        $scope.a = $scope.fnumber;
        $scope.b = $scope.snumber;
        $scope.sum = $scope.a + $scope.b;
      
    }; 
}]);
```

Html

```html
 <table ng-controller="AddSum">
            <tr>
                <td>Enter First Number:</td>
                <td><input ng-model="fnumber"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Enter Second Number:</td>
                <td><input ng-modle="snumber"  /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><button ng-click="add()">SUM</button></td>
                <td><p>Sum:{{sum}}</p></td>
            </tr>
           
  </table>
```

---

its not working, Please see modified code.

```js
                
                app.controller('AddSum', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.sum = 0;
    $scope.add = function (fnumber,snumber) {
        $scope.a = $scope.fnumber;
        $scope.b = $scope.snumber;
        $scope.sum = parseInt($scope.a) + parseInt($scope.b);
      
    }; 
}]);
```

```html
 <table ng-controller="AddSum">
            <tr>
                <td>Enter First Number:</td>
                <td><input ng-model="fnumber"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Enter Second Number:</td>
                <td><input ng-model="snumber" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><button ng-click="add(fnumber,snumber)">SUM</button></td>
                <td><p>Sum:{{sum}}</p></td>
            </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i got the solution.

app.controller('AddSum1', function ($scope) {

```
$scope.add = function (num1, num2) {
    $scope.sum = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2);
};
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo.

change

```
 <td><input ng-modle="snumber"  /></td>
```

to

```
<td><input ng-model="snumber"  /></td>
```

Then you need to parse the input as a number

changing 
      `$scope.sum = $scope.a + $scope.b;`
to 
      `$scope.sum = parseInt($scope.a) + parseInt($scope.b);`
will do the trick although you will want to do something a little more elegant.